# Copy data-src attribute to img src when data-src is located in div above using array to apply to multiple img's

Tags: arrays, srcset

> The current script I am trying to use (image defer) wants to locate the data-src attribute in the img element. My data-src is not in that element but located in the div it is contained in. I need to change the script so the it finds the data-src in the div above each img element I am changing. The last picture D works because it has the data-src in the img element. (For reference).

```js
function init() {
  var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
    if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
      imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src', imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
    }
  }
}
window.onload = init;
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-12">
      <div class="responsive-picture" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+A">
        <picture>
          <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
          <source media="(min-width: 64em)" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+A">
          <source media="(min-width: 40em)" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/640x480/000/ffffff.jpg&text=meduim+A">
          <source media="screen" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/ffffff.jpg&text=small+A">
          <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
          <img alt="Placeholder Picture" src="transparent.gif">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="responsive-picture" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+B">
        <picture>
          <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
          <source media="(min-width: 64em)" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+B">
          <source media="(min-width: 40em)" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/640x480/000/ffffff.jpg&text=medium+B">
          <source media="screen" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/ffffff.jpg&text=small+B">
          <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
          <img alt="Placeholder Picture" src="transparent.gif">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="responsive-picture" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+C">
        <picture>
          <img alt="Placeholder Picture" src="transparent.gif" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+C">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="responsive-picture">
        <picture>
          <img alt="Placeholder Picture" src="transparent.gif" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ff0000.jpg&text=large+D" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ff0000.jpg&text=large+D">
        </picture>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I found something here on stackoverflow.

```
$('.responsive-picture').each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$this.find("img").attr("src", $this.data("src"))
```

});

> This updates the first 3 image src's.

Comment: We can build on what you have (.each).  But the correct way is not to manually enumerate.  Let the framework enumerate for you.  An example, var elems = $("div[data-src]");

Answer (score 0):

This definitely works.  I will create a fiddle tomorrow.  Please make sure to add a reference to JQUERY".  Also, note the code changes I commented:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    @*MAKE SURE YOU HAVE A reference to jquery here-I have it in my bundle*@
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#aBtn").click(function () {
                var elems = $("div[data-src]");
                var lastOne = elems[elems.length - 1]
                //replacing the last one with C, so C is shown twice-last two
                var grandchild = lastOne.children[0].children[0]
                grandchild.srcset = "https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+C"
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="aBtn" value="BtnTriggerInsteadOfOnLoad" />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="columns small-12">
            <div class="responsive-picture" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+A">
                <picture>
                    <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
                    <source media="(min-width: 64em)" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+A">
                    <source media="(min-width: 40em)" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/640x480/000/ffffff.jpg&text=meduim+A">
                    <source media="screen" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/ffffff.jpg&text=small+A">
                    <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
                    <img alt="Placeholder Picture" src="transparent.gif">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="responsive-picture" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+B">
                <picture>
                    <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
                    <source media="(min-width: 64em)" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+B">
                    <source media="(min-width: 40em)" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/640x480/000/ffffff.jpg&text=medium+B">
                    <source media="screen" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/320x240/000/ffffff.jpg&text=small+B">
                    <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
                    <img alt="Placeholder Picture" src="transparent.gif">
                </picture>
            </div>
            <div class="responsive-picture" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+C">
                <picture>
                    <img alt="Placeholder Picture" src="transparent.gif" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ffffff.jpg&text=large+C">
                </picture>
            </div>
            @*I PUT THE SRCE BACK ON THE DIV like it is suppose to be*@
            <div class="responsive-picture" data-src="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ff0000.jpg&text=large+D">
                <picture>
                    <img alt="Placeholder Picture" src="transparent.gif" srcset="https://dummyimage.com/1024x768/000/ff0000.jpg&text=large+D"> 
                </picture>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To be clear, I am trying to copy the data-src url to the src for each responsive-picture element on page load. The software program I am using on export overwrites the src url with a transparent image for lazy load. I am prevented from adding any attributes to the img in the software program. I am allowed to add the data-src attribute to the div class responsive-picture before export from the program. I now need jquery to replace all img src (images) that I might add to the html page (could be 2 could be 20) with each data-src per div. (Ignore the last picture reference if it is confusing)

Comment: In other words I need to keep the src but copy the data-src url to it for each picture I might add....global function based on data-src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> There was another solution on the same question that addressed this issue on stackoverflow that received higher votes.

```
$('.responsive-picture').each(function(){
// grab a reference to the current div
var $el = $(this);
// get the url from its data-src attribute
var url = $el.data('src');
// create a new Image element to load into
var img = new Image();
// load callback for the new image
img.onload = function() {
    // find the first image inside the div
    // and change its src to the url we just loaded
    $el.find('img')[0].src = url;
}
// set the src of our temp Image to start loading
img.src = url;
```

});

> Here is the link to give credit to posters
>
> Would this avoid manually enumeration ? Thanks again !

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14163164/8080326